# Maven inheritance does not work when invoking plugin goals from command line

Tags: maven-3

I have a multi module project. There is a parent pom in which I have added the maven-dependency plugin to the plugin management section. I have not tied this plugin's execution to a phase. In one of the child modules pom.xml, I have added this same plugin with different configuration.
However when I execute from the command line

mvn dependency:copy

Then only my parent pom plugin configuration executes for the maven-dependency plugin and all the child modules are skipped.  Why is this? Does inheritance work only if plugins are tied to a specific phase?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this is: If you try to run maven via command like you did you are calling a plugin but you will not run the life cyclce which is needed to get the inheritance mechanism take care of the pom files. In your examples if you would start the life cylce with something like:

```
mvn package
```

or something similar like:

```
mvn verify
```

all your sub modules would be visited during the life cyclce.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is if I specify a phase then the child modules also execute that phase - I wish to avoid this since I only want to execute the dependency copy goal. Is there anyway I could specify a phase and have only my necessary goal execute and have the inheritance mechanism?

Comment: The question is what your childs are? jar files? If yes than the life cycle will be run through you might create a child which has the packaging type pom which might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Tried what you had mentioned and found that other plugins like antrun plugin, etc are inherited by the child poms no matter the packaging and the inheritance mechanism works even if I just specify the goal and don't tie to a lifecycle phase. The problem seems to be specific only to the maven dependency plugin regarding inheritance. Maybe the way the plugin has been written does not allow inheritance.